# Use any join result is same. Why so?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `A` and `B`:

- `A` with 3 rows all 1, 1, 1 with single column
- `B` with 2 rows all 1 1 with single column

I used all available joins on these the tables the o/p is same:

```
A   B
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
```

How are these joins working?

I face these question in a interview with a MNC.

Comment: What do you mean by "all available joins"? What are the exact queries you make? (It might not be strictly necessary to know this in order to answer your question, but presenting all relevant details would be a good habit to get into when you're asking a question on SO.)

Comment: You're getting the same result due to the columns having the same data, so the joins will always match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of executing a query works in the following manner.

Suppose you have a query

```
select A.Id, B.Id 
From A
inner join B on A.Id = B.Id
```

Sql server engine first do the cross join between A and B creating a list of all records ( rows of A * rows of B) in a virtual table.
Then it filters the records based on the join.
Like in the example, the join is inner join and condition is A.Id = B.Id. 
In your specific case, all the rows will satisfy the criteria of join, so all the records will be returned.

Now you can assume the same for all other joins (left outer, right outer, full outer, cross join).

In this specific case, all joins will give the same output.

Check the URL : http://www.databaseskill.com/4841542/ for further details of a query's logical processing phases.

Also there is a good video about this on youtube. You can check that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1lIaTJ_oDM

Comment: Roopesh is that you the founder of msbiguide.com

Comment: No. But I am working on some site of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

Check this to understand the different types of joins:
http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

In your case, the result is the same with all join types, since your values are the same in all tables.

**Join types explained**

*FULL OUTER JOIN*

Picks all records from the left (first) and right (second) tables, with matching records from both sides where available. If there is no match, the missing side will be filled with NULLs.

*LEFT OUTER JOIN*

Left join picks all records from the left (first) table, then passes all matching records from the right (second) table. Where no match found, the right table's columns will be filled with NULLs

*RIGHT OUTER JOIN*

Same as the left join, just the order is changed.

*INNER JOIN*

Inner join picks all records from the two joined tables where the join condition is true. (This is the intersection of the two sets of records)

*CROSS JOIN*

Creates ALL combinations of the records from both tables.

** T-SQL (MSSQL) Test code **

```
DECLARE @test1 TABLE (num INT, name VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @test2 TABLE (num INT, value VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @test1 (num, name) VALUES (1, 'first')
INSERT INTO @test1 (num, name) VALUES (2, 'second')
INSERT INTO @test1 (num, name) VALUES (3, 'third / 1')
INSERT INTO @test1 (num, name) VALUES (3, 'third / 2')

INSERT INTO @test2 (num, value) VALUES (1, 'one / 1')
INSERT INTO @test2 (num, value) VALUES (1, 'one / 2')
INSERT INTO @test2 (num, value) VALUES (3, 'three')
INSERT INTO @test2 (num, value) VALUES (4, 'four')


SELECT
    *
FROM
    @test1 T1
    FULL OUTER JOIN @test2 T2
        ON T1.num = T2.num

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @test1 T1
    LEFT JOIN @test2 T2
        ON T1.num = T2.num

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @test1 T1
    RIGHT JOIN @test2 T2
        ON T1.num = T2.num

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @test1 T1
    INNER JOIN @test2 T2
        ON T1.num = T2.num

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @test1 T1
    CROSS JOIN @test2 T2
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation, in case the link goes dead.

Comment: As you wish :) (OK, this is not short :))

Comment: +1 Good job! Now, it wouldn't really matter as much if the link were to go dead, since anyone looking at your answer would get to knows the basics of each type.